# Is this topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ well studied?

Tags: gn.general-topology, p-adic-numbers

Let $\|\cdot\|_p$ denote the $p$-adic norm on $\mathbb{Q}$. For the whole set of primes $P$ consider the topology which is generated with prebase of open sets $V_{p,\varepsilon}(x) = \{y\in\mathbb{Q} : \|x-y\|_p<\varepsilon\}$, $p\in P$. Is there any reference for this topology?

Comment: It seems to be plainly the topology induced by inclusion into $\prod_p\mathbf{Q}_p$.

Comment: Yes, it is a prebasis.

Comment: Reminds me of the [Adele ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring).

Comment: @darkl It's not the adele topology. For the adele topology, one should add $\mathbf{Z}$ in the prebasis. This topology is weaker as $\mathbf{Z}$ is not open. Unlike the adele topology, the completion is not locally compact.

Comment: It is important not to add $\mathbb{R}$ norm because in many cases of other rings these rings aren't normed rings but if there are primes we can define the adic norms as in $\mathbb{Z}$ case

Comment: This is a countable metric space with no isolated points, so by a theorem of Sierpiński it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ with its usual metric as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Of course, this does not preserve the group structure.